# Ng-repeat firing more than once with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, momentjs, ng-show

I'm pretty new to Angular, and I am not sure if I am violating any best practices. I am building a calendar app that when you select a day, it shows availability times for each day:

```
    <div class="panel" ng-controller="timeCtrl">
        <a class="time" 
            ng-repeat="timeObj in timeObjs"
            ng-click="timeObj.isActive = true"
            ng-class="{ 'is-active' : timeObj.isActive}"
            ng-show="weekService.selectedDay.date() === timeObj.time.date()"
            >
            <span class="time__text">{{ timeObj.time.format('h:mm a') }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

In the ng-show, I compare the date of the day of the week selected with the time chosen (which has access to the date in the time obj). When I select a day that was already previously selected, however, then I get 2x the time objects that I need. This process keeps repeating itself (more time objects are made when I click on a day that was previously selected).

Since I am new to Angular, I feel as though even solving the problem the way I intend it to be solved may not be the best way to do this. I am wondering if my use of ng-show and ng-repeat is problematic in any way, and whether I should be using ng-view here?

Comment: because each binding over an HTML gets evaluated on each digest cycle..like here `ng-show` expression is getting evaluated on `ng-click` which runs digest cycle after execute the expression provided to it..Likewise there are many directive has `$apply` method wrapper which runs digest cycle to keep HTML binding updated

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding this process. When you say "binding over an HTML" are you talking about the <span> {{ ... }} </span> part of the code? Also the ng-show getting evaluated after ng-click is desired behavior.

Comment: yes it include `{{}}`(interpolated directive) expression & `ng-*` directive, basically this expression are put into angular watcher object, you could find that inside the `$$watchers` object inside `$scope`..basically those expression gets evaluated on each digest cycle.

Comment: So are you saying that the digest cycle is running twice per ng-click and that this is causing duplication?

Comment: no...it runs once per click..because the way `ng-click` directive has been wrapped with `$apply` method which is responsible to call digest cycle..you could look at [this answer](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) for further digging into it.

Comment: Looks like a good article. I'm going to read it now. Do you, however, have a solution to this problem? Should I write my ng-click differently?